# SegmentedButton is not updating its state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container and this container have a row with a text and a button ,  the button here show a modal bottom sheet , and Inside it I want to make My segmented button so the user choose one of the categories , the probllem is in the segmented button ,  it is sticking to that first value and it is not updating to new values when I click on other values.

I will provide all my BlocBuilder

```
BlocBuilder<CategoryBloc, CategoryState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    var selectedCategory = state.revenueCategories[2].category;
                    revenuesCategoryController.text = selectedCategory;
                    return InputsForm(
                      formKey: revenuesKey,
                      dateController: dateController,
                      category: revenuesCategoryController,
                      selectCategory: () async {
                        showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return Container(
                              height: size.height * 0.5,
                              width: size.width,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                              child: SegmentedButton(
                                showSelectedIcon: true,
                                onSelectionChanged: (Set<String> newSelection) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedCategory = newSelection.first;
                                  });
                                },
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    BorderSide.none,
                                  ),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                segments: List.generate(
                                    state.revenueCategories.length, (index) {
                                  return ButtonSegment<String>(
                                    value:
                                        state.revenueCategories[index].category,
                                    label: Text(state
                                        .revenueCategories[index].category),
                                  );
                                }),
                                selected: <String>{selectedCategory},
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      amount: revenuesAmountController,
                      note: revenuesNoteController,
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

I tried to make the list fixed and created the ButtonSegment one by one ,but the same problem , maybe it is a value problem or something Idk.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the "selected category" in your SegmentedButton as I read from the code you copied.

Replace your SegmentedButton code with as:

```
SegmentedButton(
 showSelectedIcon: true,
onSelectionChanged: (Set<String> newSelection) {
 setState(() {
  selectedCategory = newSelection.isNotEmpty ? newSelection.first :  selectedCategory;
 });
 },
 style: ButtonStyle(
 side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
  BorderSide.none,
 ),
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
  ),
  ),
 segments: List.generate(state.revenueCategories.length, (index) {
 return ButtonSegment<String>(
  value: state.revenueCategories[index].category,
  label: Text(state.revenueCategories[index].category),
  );
}),
 selected: <String>{selectedCategory},
),
```

if the new selection is empty, meaning the user taps on the already selected segment, it retains the current selected category. Otherwise, it updates to the newly selected category.

Comment: The thing is it is updating in the background and when I added some print to show if the selected item is updating it is actually updating , just the UI is not updating , and also I noticed that when I click to any of the items it doesn't update but If I just drag the bottom sheet to the bottom a little bit it actually update the selected item on the UI

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling this same issue for 2 days.  Try declaring the selectedCategory in the State but outside the build function.

This line:

var selectedCategory = state.revenueCategories[2].category;

This worked for me